# Why are there so many Close votes in the Review queues in Math Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, review, closing, closed-questions

Currently there are over 300 Close votes in the Review queues in Math Stack Exchange.  Why so many?

Comment: This is effectively the second largest site on the Stack Exchange network (after Stackoverflow).

Comment: Many people post junk, and many others post questions that are not yet suitable. Math SE is much better than most sites at following its policies and using the systems intended, rather than answering every duplicate separately or doing everyone's work for them.

Comment: [Sturgeon's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law), combined with the fact that Math SE is one of the largest sites on the SE network.

Comment: 300? That seems low, in my historical experience. People have been working hard.